# What is the java config equivalent to tcp-outbound-gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I have the following spring-integration XML config

```
<ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outboundClient"
        request-channel="requestChannel"
        reply-channel="string2ObjectChannel"
        connection-factory="clientConnectionFactory"
        request-timeout="10000"
        reply-timeout="10000"/>
```

How can I write the Java config equivalent of the above? 
I thought the equivalent would be

```
@Bean
public TcpOutboundGateway outboundClient() {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory());
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(true);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setReplyChannel(string2ObjectChannel());
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(10000);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setSendTimeout(10000);
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}
```

But I couldn't find a way to set the request channel.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You also need to call the method `afterPropertiesSet()`, and this won't use any registered convertors via a `ConvertionService`. The way I tacle this types of problems is by looking at the source code, as spring does quite a lot of magic behind the scenes.

Comment: I did look at the source code, but there's no way to set the request channel. Initially I thought the OutputChannel is the request channel, but the setReplyChannel is actually setting the outputChannel internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config looks good, but you should know in addition that any Spring Integration Consumer component consists of two main objects: `MessageHandler` (`TcpOutboundGateway` in your case) and `EventDrivenConsumer` for `subscriable` `input-channel` or `PollingConsumer` if `input-channel` is `Pollable`.

So, since you already have the first, handling, part you need another consuming. For this purpose Spring Integration suggests to mark your `@Bean` with endpoint annotations:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel")
public TcpOutboundGateway outboundClient() {
```

See more in the [Spring Integration Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15188).

However to allow such a annotation process (or any other Spring Integration infrastructure) you have to mark your `@Configuration` with `@EnableIntegration`.

Also consider to use [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) to have more gain from JavaConfig.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I got another error after adding @ServiceActivator, it says org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7b306b9f.requestChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Comment: It also seems that whatever I put as inputChannel either on <code>@ServiceActivator</code> or <code>@Transformer</code>, the bean is not subscribing to the channel.

Comment: Good catch! Sorry: I have missed mention `@EnableIntegration`. See my edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I have that annotation already. I put both <code> @EnableIntegration </code>
and <code>@IntegrationComponentScan</code> to <code>@Configuration</code> file

Comment: Would you mind to share your whole `@Configuration` ? And it is interesting how you check the application.

Comment: Thanks @artem-bilan, Finally I figure out that I forgot to put the `@Configuration` annotation. I initially had the spring-integration XML config using `@ImportResource` from the main Java config, then I start creating the java version of the spring-integration XML config, and import from the main config. I put the `@EnableIntegration` and `@IntegrationComponentScan` but I forgot to put the `@Configuration`. The interesting thing is that the `@Bean` on those configuration are created by the spring context. That's why I didn't realize that I forgot to put the `@Configuration`

Comment: How I check the application is that I have a set of integration test that worked with the XML config, so I just keep running those test and see if the java config works properly.