# what is equivalent of <tcp-outbound-channel-adapter> in java config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-java-config

I have the spring integration XML config with following bean

```
<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundClient"
channel="input"
connection-factory="client"/>
```

I thought the equivalent in java config would be

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input", requiresReply = "true")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler outboundClient() {
    TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpSendingMessageHandler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    tcpSendingMessageHandler.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory());
    tcpSendingMessageHandler.setRetryInterval(10000);
    tcpSendingMessageHandler.setClientMode(true);
    return tcpSendingMessageHandler;
}
```

However, in the log, I see

```
TcpListener exiting - no listener and not single use
```

and I can't receive the reply from server.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TcpSendingMessageHandler` is for one-way usage - just for sending messages to the TCP socket.

So, your config looks good and seems for me it should work.

> TcpListener exiting - no listener and not single use

Is just `DEBUG` message from the `TcpNetConnection` which indicates that your component is `one-way`.

Therefore it is normal that you can't receive a reply from the server. Because you only send message to there.

To have `request/reply` scenarios consider to use [`TcpOutboundGateway`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796482/what-is-the-java-config-equivalent-to-tcp-outbound-gateway).

Comment: Thanks @artem-bilan. However in the spring integration documentation, it is mentioned: `The gateways will automatically correlate messages. However, an outbound gateway should only be used for relatively low-volume use. 
Therefore, for high-volume messages, consider using a collaborating pair of channel adapters. However, you will need to provide collaboration logic.`

Comment: And ? That's correct. To receive messages from the server you must add `<int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter>`. And pay attention: *only* receive. So, they are exactly that pair for collaboration. But yes, they is no automatic logic for correlation, hence you should support it yourself.

Comment: So I've put that inbound channel adapter, however I got `no output-channel or replyChannel header available`. Does the header being serialized as well and sent over the network?

Comment: Yes, it is possible: `<header-channels-to-string>` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-enricher)

Comment: But even that alone won't work because TCP has no standard way to convey headers; you need to add them to the message payload. We do provide a [mechanism for that](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ip.html#ip-headers) but it only works if the other side is Spring Integration too (or understands the headers and returns them in the reply). An alternative to solving the gateway performance issue is to use a [caching client factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ip.html#caching-cf).

Comment: So if that's the case, what's the advantage of using TCP channel adapter over TCP gateway? One of my requirement other than being able to do request/reply, I'd also need to perform publish from server side. and both server and client are using spring-integration

Comment: To do `one-way` scenarios. Like your server-side pushes. Consider we want to implement our own WebSocket protocol.